# Get the exit code of python process linux

Tags: python, linux

I have written one shell script which call python script. The execution of python script is via `nohup`.

On executing `nohup` I get the process id. Whenever I run `wait 3398` it says `bash: wait: pid 3398 is not a child of this shell`

I can see the process running in `ps -ef`

```
`lisa      3485     8  1 21:27 ?        00:00:00 python3 -u pid_watch.py`
```

How can I get the exit code of this python code whenever it's execution is completed?

Following is the shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash

export arguments=${@}

username=""
while getopts 'u:' OPT; do
case "$OPT" in
        u) username=$OPTARG;;
esac
done

`nohup stdbuf -oL python3 -u pid_watch.py > "pid_watch.log" 2>&1 &`

output2=`pgrep -fn "pid_watch.py" -u "$username"`
echo -n  "$output2"
```

pid_watch.py:

```
import time

print("Hello World")
time.sleep(180)
print("End")
```

How can I get the exit code of this python code whenever it's execution is completed?

Comment: Why are you putting your command inside a command substitution? There's absolutely no benefit to `$(foo >file &)` over just `foo >file &`; that's the same with backtick syntax too: you get only disadvantages by obfuscating the process tree and making startup slightly slower.

Comment: Also, `export arguments=${@}` is unfixably broken. You cannot store an array in a string, or in an environment variable; even if you make it slightly more correct so it doesn't treat extra arguments as things for `export` to process, it'll still lose the distinction between `yourprogram "argument one" "argument two"` and `yourprogram "argument" "one" "argument" "two"`

Comment: Anyhow -- like the error message says, a program can only wait for _immediate_ children. When you put a bunch of extra processes (like subshells) between parent and child, you can no longer `wait` for the child from the parent. Think about throwing out all this code altogether and using a proper process supervision system like systemd (on Linux), launchd (on MacOS), etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some background information. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to run a program in background and later wait for it? Why do you (think you) need `nohup`?